# How to show Sum of Columns Grid.Mvc List

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new at asp.net and trying to understand mvc principles. I have a Grid.MVC based list which allows me to create a sortable, filterable, paged list.

My problem is, I want to add footer for my columns to show the sum of the values at column. I have examined documentation of Grid.Mvc but I couldn't find anyway to make it.

```
model IEnumerable<Finalizor.Models.Server>


@using GridMvc.Html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Gridmvc.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js")"></script>

<div class="code-cut">
    @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Add(c => c.Name).Titled("Name").Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add(c => c.Surname).Titled("Surname").Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add(c => c.Job).Titled("Job").Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add(c => c.Salary).Titled("Salary").Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add(c => c.Department).Titled("Department").Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add()
                        .Encoded(false)
                        .Sanitized(false)
                        .SetWidth(30)
                        .RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = o.PersonalID }));

                    }).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true).WithGridItemsCount("Total Personal")
</div>
```

This is my view, very simple I think. For example, I need to filter staff according to their departments and jobs, I can do this until this point but also I have to see sum of their salaries at the end of salary column. But not all the personal, only the staff that I've filtered, so I mean staff on the list after filtering.

Grid.MVC has a sample project very much like this [here](http://gridmvc.azurewebsites.net/?grid-page=3)

I think there's a way maybe they've specified at their code but I don't know where.

https://github.com/leniel/Grid.Mvc/blob/master/GridMvc

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every table row (`<tr>` element) in a `Grid.MVC` table has a class appended to it called `grid-row`.

You can write a jQuery function to loop through every `<tr class="grid-row">` on the page -> find the salary column and add the values together.

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var s1 = new Server { PersonalID = 1, Name = "Name 1", Surname = "Surname 1", Department = "IT", Job = "Dev", Salary = 10.00M };
        var s2 = new Server { PersonalID = 1, Name = "Name 2", Surname = "Surname 2", Department = "IT", Job = "Dev", Salary = 10.00M };
        var s3 = new Server { PersonalID = 1, Name = "Name 3", Surname = "Surname 3", Department = "IT", Job = "Dev", Salary = 10.00M };
        var s4 = new Server { PersonalID = 1, Name = "Name 4", Surname = "Surname 4", Department = "IT", Job = "Dev", Salary = 2.10M };
        var s5 = new Server { PersonalID = 1, Name = "Name 5", Surname = "Surname 5", Department = "IT", Job = "Dev", Salary = 2.20M };
        var s6 = new Server { PersonalID = 1, Name = "Name 6", Surname = "Surname 6", Department = "IT", Job = "Dev", Salary = 2.33M };
        return View(new List<Server> { s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6 });
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@using GridMvc.Html
@model IEnumerable<MVC_WebGrid_example.Models.Server>

@{
    Layout = null;
}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var salary = 0.00;

        $("tr.grid-row").each(function () {
            var tr = $(this);
            var rows = $(tr).children();
            var amount = rows[3].innerHTML;
            amount = amount.replace(",", ".");
            amount = parseFloat(amount);

            salary += amount;
        });

        salary = salary.toFixed(2);
        var trTotals = "<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>" + salary + "</td><td></td><td></td></tr>"
        $("tr.grid-row:last").after(trTotals);

        $("#salaryTotal").text("Salary total is - " + salary);

    });
</script>
<div class="code-cut">
    @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Add(c => c.Name).Titled("Name").Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add(c => c.Surname).Titled("Surname").Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add(c => c.Job).Titled("Job").Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add(c => c.Salary).Titled("Salary").Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add(c => c.Department).Titled("Department").Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add()
                        .Encoded(false)
                        .Sanitized(false)
                        .SetWidth(30)
                        .RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = o.PersonalID }));
                    }).WithPaging(3).Sortable(true).WithGridItemsCount("Total Personal")
</div>
<h1 id="salaryTotal" style="color:red;"></h1>
```

**Output:**

[image: Calculating column totals in jQuery]

Comment: Yes! I knew that we should use jQuery but I didn't realize there's a class "grid-row". It's totally working fine right now. Thank you so much for your help. I think, I should dive deeper at jQuery to make changes at this template. Again, thanks a lot !